# Como acceder a una estructura dentro de otra estructura

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente codigo de ejemplo en el cual intento insertar una estructura dentro de otra, pero luego no se como acceder a sus campos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Ejemplo{
    void* data;
} ejemplo;

typedef struct Dentro{
    char* dataDentro;
} dentro;

int main(){
    char nombre[] = "Cris\0";

    ejemplo* estructura = malloc(sizeof(ejemplo));
    dentro* estructuraInterior = malloc(sizeof(dentro));

    estructuraInterior->dataDentro = nombre;
    estructura->data = estructuraInterior;

    printf("\n%s\n ", estructura->data->dataDentro);

    return 0;
}
```

Esto no funciona y produce un error en la linea del printf

> error: member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or
>         union

¿Como se debe realizar esto para que funcione?

Comment: ¿Dónde declaras `test`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster disculpa ahi corregí el codigo

Comment: No es necesario el `\0` al final de `char nombre[] = "Cris\0";`. C ya se encarga de añadir el carácter de finalización de cadena en literales de texto.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster gracias por el dato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás des-referenciando un puntero a `void`.

---

A priori estás accediendo correctamente a la sub-estructura, pero no hay manera de interpretar lo que es el puntero `data` contenido en `Ejemplo`. Dado que `void` no es un `Dentro`, el operador flecha (`->`) no podrá acceder a `dataDentro`.

#### Solución.

Aplica una transformación  de tipos:

```
ejemplo* estructura = malloc(sizeof(ejemplo));
dentro* estructuraInterior = malloc(sizeof(dentro));

estructuraInterior->dataDentro = nombre;
estructura->data = estructuraInterior;

printf("\n%s\n ", ((dentro *)estructura->data)->dataDentro);
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^
//                 Transforma el puntero a 'void' a puntero a 'dentro'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero, haces

```
typedef struct Ejemplo{
  void* data;
} ejemplo;
```

y luego, intentas acceder a `data` como si fuera una `dentro`, cosa que provoca el error.

La solución mas simple: *predeclarar* `struct Dentro`:

```
struct Dentro;

typedef struct Ejemplo{
  struct Dentro* data;
} ejemplo;

typedef struct Dentro {
...
```

Comment: Gracias, se que eso sería más simple pero yo di eso como ejemplo en realidad data puede contener otras estructuras  distintas por esto necesito que sea void

Comment: @CristoferFuentes No entendí correctamente tu pregunta. Otra vez será :-)